# ERROR when running npm install --save@ionic-native/local-notifications

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, npm, cross-platform

I'm trying to add LocalNotifications plugins to my ionic app by running the following:

```
=> npm install --save@ionic-native/local-notifications
```

I get the following error:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 
(node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Comment: It is obvious that isn't an error. It's a warning. One you can safely ignore because the fsevents package is only good on Mac OS.

Comment: but it refuse to install the plugin . every time i enter the command it gives me the same warning without installing the plugin

Comment: That seems to be because the command is wrong. Try this: `npm install --save @ionic-native/local-notifications`. There is a space between `--save` and the package name.

Comment: thanks so much it finally worked ...thanks